# (EF 5 + .net 4,5) escalating transaction to DTC when querying using EF-Linq and SqlConnection

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

We recently upgraded our project to use .net 4.5 and EF 5. We use traditional SqlConnection to query legacy part of application and EF-Linq for rest.

After upgrade code that used to work fine started throwing error regarding MSDTC service being not available. Turning MSDTC service on solves the problems.

**Question is why my transactions are getting escalated? Has anything changed in .net 4.5 or EF 5?**

For example i have piece of code wrapped in TransactionScope making two updates. First using SqlConnection then second using EF+Linq. Both using exactly same connectionstrings part, connecting to same database in sql server 2012. It get's escalated to DTC. And it used to not escalate using .net 4 and EF 4X.